# What commands does WHM/Cpanel run over SSH when you do an rsync backup?

Tags: cpanel, backups, whm, ssh

I have an account at rsync.net and am trying to point WHM "rsync" backups to it.

Obviously "rsync.net" has rsync installed, and they also have a small list of common UNIX commands in their environment:

https://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/remote_commands.html

... but when I run my WHM rsync backup it errors out with:

> Unable to send ... to destination rsync.net ...

... and there is no other information or error.

I *think* the problem is that WHM backup is not just running `rsync`, it is running one or more other commands, remotely, over SSH - like this:

```
ssh user@host ls -asl what/ever
```

... and one or more of those commands is not present in the rsync.net environment.

They have said they would consider *adding* the missing commands if I could identify what they are - does anyone know what UNIX commands WHM runs, remotely over SSH, when it performs an rsync backup ?

For instance, if you check the "minimum free disk space" checkbox, I assume it would have to try running `df` on the remote system ?